# How to split a knowledge graph to train, valid, test dataset for knowledge graph completion task?

Tags: data-processing, knowledge-graph, graph-neural-network

I'm working on my own knowledge graph for knowledge graph completion task. Most of such tasks use the open source FB15K dataset, which has been divided into train,valid,test. But I didn't find any useful code to guide me how to divide the dataset like FB15K. Could anyone recommend some related repo to follow? Thanks!

I've used the Randomlinksplit function in pyg, but it seems not fit my requirement.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.